# Conectar base de datos SQL Server con Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, ubuntu, ssh

Tengo este código que empece, para poder conectarme a mi servidor de `SQL Server` por medio de `Python` en `Ubuntu`, todo los componentes de:
`server, user, password, base` ya me asegure de que sean correctos.

Pero al ejecutar el archivo de nombre `bot.py` me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he logrado corregirlo, no se que estoy haciendo mal :(.

De antemano les agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Santiago prueba a pasar los parámetros por nombre y no por posición, no estoy seguro pero creo que el segundo parámetro era el puerto, es decir haz: `conexion_sql = pymysql.connect(host=server, user=user, passwd=password, db=base)`. Por otro lado, mirate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150524/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-via-pymssql por si alguna de las ideas que dan te ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: No aún así no me agarra, Pero estuve pensando para poder usar el pymssql además de instalar el componente para python, tengo que tener instalado alguno otra paquetería en ubuntu ?

Comment: Si, en especial, `freetds`. Deberian ser instaladas antes de instalar pymssql.  Mírate el enlace a la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pymssql-python-development) de Microsoft a ver si te ayuda (baja hasta "Ubuntu Linux").

Comment: Si exacto me faltaba eso y un comentó más por lo que vi en la página, ahora si agarró :)

Comment: Santiago si funciona voy a crear una respuesta ya que los comentarios pueden desaparecer y puede ser de ayuda a otros usuarios con el mismo problema, la verdad es que presupuse lo de las dependencias, has hecho bién en comentarlo. Saludos.

Comment: Ok gracias espero tu respuesta :)

Comment: Santiago ya está publicada, es simplemete lo que hemos ido comentando para que quede para la posteridad... XD. Si aparte de estos cambios has hecho algo más para que funcione considera comentarlo. Un saludo.

Comment: Si ya vote, te agradezco la ayuda :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error en este caso se debía a dos factores:

- Falta de las dependencias necesarias, en especial del paquete [freetds-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=freetds-dev), implementación  del protocolo TDS (Tabular Data Stream) y que es el que permite la comunicación nativa con SQL-Server.

  El procedimiento para la instalación correcta de pymssql para hacerlo funcionar con SQL Server en Ubuntu es el siguiente:

  - Instalación de las dependencias:

    > $ sudo apt-get  update
    >   $ sudo apt-get --assume-yes install freetds-dev freetds-bin
    >   $ sudo apt-get --assume-yes install python-dev python-pip
  - Instalar `pymssql` (en el sistema o en entorno virtual según se prefiera):

    > $ pip install pymssql

  Para más información ver la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pymssql-python-development) de Microsoft al respecto.
- Es recomedable pasar los parámetros de conexión por nombre y no por posición. Si pasamos los parámetros por posición y nos saltamos alguno para que quede con el valor por defecto (como el puerto) tendremos errores como es lógico:

  ```
  server = "xx.xxx.x.xxx"
  user = "usuario"
  password = "1234"
  base = "Mi_base_de_datos"

  conexion_sql = pymysql.connect(host=server, user=user, passwd=password, db=base)
  ```